# Disable Prestashop's Shopping cart and payment function

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop, payment, shopping-cart

I know shop cart and payment is the core of a e-commerce software but I want to know whether it is possible to disable the Shopping Cart and payment in Prestashop (1.6+) due to the operation requirement? (include front and back office) Prestashop will be used as a order processing system only at this sceneio. Thanks!

Comment: <Catalog mode> option can't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In backoffice `Preferences -> Products` turn on `Catalog mode` checkbox.

Comment: This option can be used in front office only but not back office

Comment: not sure what do you mean in "payment" in backoffice - do not allow to manage orders? Just create user with limited permissions, give access e.g. only to Catalog part.

Comment: disable payment function too. No payment need.

Comment: Pretsashop do not allow customers to pay through backoffice

Comment: Actually my requirement include 2 issues, the 1st is front office, <Catalog mode> meet the requirement, the 2nd is all of users need to create order thru back office directly instead of add lines from shopping cart, also all order have no payment needs. Certainly users don't hope to see relative payment block and shopping cart show in the screen. Please help!

Comment: I can't imagine why need to use exactly this strange way, but by default - no way. Third party modules maybe, but I saw no modules that allow restrict access for backoffice customer to create order only by itself. Custom coding  can do it. Or just do it thru frontofiice using custom module and user groups.